# What does (int (*)[])var1 stand for?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c99, variable-length

I found this example code and I tried to google what `(int (*)[])var1` could stand for, but I got no usefull results.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i(int n,int m,int var1[n][m]) {
    return var1[0][0];
}

int example() {
    int *var1 = malloc(100);
    return i(10,10,(int (*)[])var1);
}
```

Normally I work with VLAs in C99 so I am used to:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i(int n,int m,int var1[n][m]) {
    return var1[0][0];
}

int example() {
    int var1[10][10];
    return i(10,10,var1);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means "[cast var1 into pointer to array of int](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=%28int+%28*%29%5B%5D%29var1)".

Comment: I was going to suggest the `cdecl` tool, nice to see a web front-end for it :)

Comment: I'm confused - there's no such type as "array of int". Array types must have a size, even if it's variable. Is this type used in the cast really valid? If so, what does it mean? What is `sizeof *(int (*)[])0`?

Comment: @R.. according to [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html): "If the size of the array is unknown, N can in principle be omitted, but the resulting type, 'pointer to array of unknown size,' is useless." And behavior is an incomplete type error on gcc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typecast to a pointer that points to an array of int.

Answer (score 0):

`(int (*)[])` is a pointer to an array of `int`s.  Equivalent to the `int[n][m]`  function argument.

This is a common idiom in C: first do a malloc to reserve memory, then cast it to the desired type.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your answer, because `int[][]` is not valid C syntax and it remains unclear what you mean.

Comment: And why would you cast the return from malloc? It's a pointer-to-void, which can be assigned to any pointer type without a cast in C. (In C++ you don't use malloc in the first place, but `new`).

Comment: @Jens: I should have just shut up :)  I'm no C guru, so I could only interprete what the code meant, not see what it should have read.